# My joomla site is showing blank

Tags: joomla1.5

I have exported my joomla site from beta release nvpccbeta.com to trying to be nvpcc.org
and it is showing blank I know configuration.php is running so I checked erro log it is chowing me
href='function.main'>function.main]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 10006 is not allowed to access /var/www/vhosts/nvpcc.org/httpdocs/includes/defines.php owned by uid 0 in /var/www/vhosts/nvpcc.org/httpdocs/index.php on line 21
[client 68.224.6.162] PHP Warning:  main(/var/www/vhosts/nvpcc.org/httpdocs/includes/defines.php) [function.main]: failed to open stream: Success in /var/www/vhosts/nvpcc.org/httpdocs/index.php on line 21
I have changed my php.ini safe mode to off and still showing same problem. Need help thank you

Comment: Yes did and thank you for your suggestion actually the problem was you need disable the base path to null I fixed one problem they are many problem to be fixed one word never go Vpesk if you want to use scripts html files are fine

Answer (score 0):

It could be your Live Site variable in your configuration.php file.  Did you change that?  If you don't, it will give you problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error listed about says that the user that your webserver is running as can't access `/var/www/vhosts/nvpcc.org/httpdocs/includes/defines.php`.  The files are owned by the wrong uid.  This is an issue with the server.

These must be ran from the web root.
I would change everything in the web root to the correct user.

```
chown -R user:group *
```

Verify folder and file permissions

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Changed safe_mode off, did you restart your web server?